# Xtend Elvis ?: operator doesn't work as expected

Tags: operators, xtend

I'm using Xtend to write an Android app, and I wanted to use the elvis operator to simplify the following (which works):

```
val c = if (projection != null) new MatrixCursor(projection) else new MatrixCursor(#[MediaStore$MediaColumns::DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore$MediaColumns::SIZE])
```

By using elvis operator, I wrote:

```
val c = new MatrixCursor(projection ?: #[MediaStore$MediaColumns::DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore$MediaColumns::SIZE])
```

which, as far as I understand, works in the same way.

However, I got this error in Eclipse: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String[]` What's wrong with it?

I'm using Xtend 2.4, the `MatrixCursor` constructor signature is `MatrixCursor(String[])`, and `projection` is defined explicitly as `String[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stumbling across a limitation of the type inference. The elvis operator is defined as something along these lines:

```
def <T> T elvis(T original, T placeholder) {
  ..
}
```

If order to bind the type variable T, both operand types are computed. Since the array literal `#[..]` is actually primarily a list literal, the binding for T is computed from `String[]` and `List<String>` rather than two `String[]`. Therefore the common supertype is `Object` so elvis is just an `Object`. You can convince the type system, that you want the second operand to be a `String[]` by explicitly casting it:

```
val c = new MatrixCursor(projection ?: #[DISPLAY_NAME, SIZE] as String[])
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know whether this will be improved in the future, or is it by design?

Comment: We are likely going to improve on that one in the future. It's currently a limitation of the type inference.